# How to "Catch and Forwarding" Intent (URL) in Kotin?

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

[image: WireFrame & Guide about what i want to ask]

---> Full Code for more details https://github.com/BUdiAKmal/CaseApp

I've been successfully pass the data, but how about the URL?
i need to open URL contained in each item to WebView Activity but by pressing the button on "Activity Details"...

> How to do it from this code?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // Start - full screen
        val window = window
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        ) // End - full screen
        
        setUpTabs() // Setup TabLayout

    } // End - OnCreate

    // Start - TabLayout
    private fun setUpTabs() {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(MainTabFragment1(), "MainTab1")
        adapter.addFragment(MainTabFragment1(), "MainTab2")
        viewPager_tabLayout.adapter = adapter
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager_tabLayout)
    } // End - TabLayout

} // End - Class
```

**MainTabFragment**

```
class MainTabFragment1 : Fragment() {
    
    lateinit var mainTabFragment1Adapter: MainTabFragment1Adapter  // Initialize Adapter
    private val sLM = LinearLayoutManager(context) // Initialize layoutManager
    val addMainTabFragment1ModelList: MutableList<MainTabFragment1Model> = ArrayList() // Initialize listModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_main_tab, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initViewMainTabFragment1() // SetUp initView listModel
        actionMainTabFragment1() // SetUp actionMainTabFragment1
        
    } // End - OnCreate

    // Start - intView listModel
    private fun initViewMainTabFragment1() {
        rv_mainTabFragment1.layoutManager = sLM
        mainTabFragment1Adapter = MainTabFragment1Adapter(requireActivity())
        rv_mainTabFragment1.adapter = mainTabFragment1Adapter

        addMainTabFragment1ModelList.add(
            MainTabFragment1Model(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585435465945-bef5a93f8849",
                "Title RVItemNo.1 MainTabFragment1",
                "Desc RVItenNo.1 MainTabFragment1",
                "https://google.com"
            )
        )
        addMainTabFragment1ModelList.add(
            MainTabFragment1Model(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487846698364-db1316e3d140",
                "Title RVItemNo.2 MainTabFragment1",
                "Desc RVItenNo.2 MainTabFragment1",
                "https://youtube.com"
            )
        )
        addMainTabFragment1ModelList.add(
            MainTabFragment1Model(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512295767273-ac109ac3acfa",
                "Title RVItemNo.3 MainTabFragment1",
                "Desc RVItenNo.3 MainTabFragment1",
                "https://gmail.com"
            )
        )
        addMainTabFragment1ModelList.add(
            MainTabFragment1Model(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525896969906-0a4806967ef0",
                "Title RVItemNo.4 MainTabFragment1",
                "Desc RVItenNo.4 MainTabFragment1",
                "https://blgger.com"
            )
        )

        mainTabFragment1Adapter.setMainTabFragment1(addMainTabFragment1ModelList)
    } // End - intView listModel

    // Start - putExtra 
    fun actionMainTabFragment1() {
        mainTabFragment1Adapter.setOnClickItemListenerMainTabFragment1(object : OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(item: View, position: Int) {
                val i = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra(
                    "titleTextMainTabFragment1",
                    mainTabFragment1Adapter
                        .getMainTabFragment1()
                        .get(position)
                        .titleTextMainTabFragment1
                )
                i.putExtra(
                    "descTextMainTabFragment1",
                    mainTabFragment1Adapter
                        .getMainTabFragment1()
                        .get(position)
                        .descTextMainTabFragment1
                )
                i.putExtra(
                    "imgURLMainTabFragment1",
                    mainTabFragment1Adapter
                        .getMainTabFragment1()
                        .get(position)
                        .imgURLMainTabFragment1
                )
                i.putExtra(
                    "btnURLMainTabFragment1",
                    mainTabFragment1Adapter
                        .getMainTabFragment1()
                        .get(position)
                        .btnURLMainTabFragment1
                )
                startActivity(i)
            }
        })
    } // End - putExtra 
    
}
```

**MainTabFragment1Adapter**

```
class MainTabFragment1Adapter(private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainTabFragment1Adapter.MainTabFragment1ViewHolder>() {

    private val MainTabFragment1Model: MutableList<MainTabFragment1Model> = mutableListOf()  // Initialize listModel
    private lateinit var onSelectedListenerMainTabFragment1: OnItemClickListener // Initialize onItemListener


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainTabFragment1ViewHolder {
        return MainTabFragment1ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_maintab_fragment1_layout, parent, false)
        )
    } // End - onCreateViewHolder
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return MainTabFragment1Model.size
    }  // End - getItem
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainTabFragment1ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.maintabfragment1BindView(MainTabFragment1Model[position])
    } // End - onBindViewHolder

    // Start - setMainTabFragment1
    fun setMainTabFragment1(data: List<MainTabFragment1Model>) {
        MainTabFragment1Model.clear()
        MainTabFragment1Model.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    } // End - setMainTabFragment1
    
    // Start - getMainTabFragment1
    fun getMainTabFragment1(): MutableList<MainTabFragment1Model> {
        return MainTabFragment1Model
    } // End - getMainTabFragment1
    
    // Start - MainTabFragment1ViewHolder
    inner class MainTabFragment1ViewHolder(maintabfragment1view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(maintabfragment1view) {
        val ivMainTabFragment1 = maintabfragment1view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_RVItem_MainTabFragment1)
        val tvTitleMainTabFragment1 = maintabfragment1view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_titleText_MainTabFragment1)
        val cvMainTabFragment1: MaterialCardView = maintabfragment1view.findViewById(R.id.cv_RVItem_MainTabFragment1)
        
        fun maintabfragment1BindView(MainTabFragment1Model: MainTabFragment1Model) {
            MainTabFragment1Model.apply {
                val image = MainTabFragment1Model.imgURLMainTabFragment1
                image.let {
                    Glide.with(itemView.context)
                        .load(it)
                        .into(ivMainTabFragment1)

                    Glide.with(itemView.context)
                        .load(it)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .fitCenter()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                }
            }
            tvTitleMainTabFragment1.text = MainTabFragment1Model.titleTextMainTabFragment1
        }

        init {
            cvMainTabFragment1.setOnClickListener { onSelectedListenerMainTabFragment1.onItemClick(it, layoutPosition) }
        }

    } // End - MainTabFragment1BindViewHolder

    // Start - OnItemListener
    fun setOnClickItemListenerMainTabFragment1(onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.onSelectedListenerMainTabFragment1 = onItemClickListener
    } // End - OnItemListener

} // End - Class
```

**MainTabFragment1Model**

```
data class MainTabFragment1Model
    (var imgURLMainTabFragment1: String?,
     var titleTextMainTabFragment1: String?,
     var descTextMainTabFragment1: String?,
     val btnURLMainTabFragment1: String?)
```

**Listener**

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(item: View, position:Int)
}
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var webView: WebView // Initialize WebView
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
        
        // Start - Assign Open New URL
        val wBS = intent
        val webSite = wBS.getStringExtra("btnURLMainTabFragment1")
        // End - Assign Open New URL
        
        // Start - full screen
        val window = window
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        ) // End - full screen

        // Start - WebView
        webView = findViewById(R.id.wv)
        webView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                view?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
                } else {
                    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
                }
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                swipe?.isRefreshing = false
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            // Start - Fix Whatsapp Acces
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(wv: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    webView.goBack()
                    return true
                }
                return false
            } // End - Fix Whatsapp Acces

        }) // End - WebView

        refreshApp() // SetUp SwipeRefresh

        // Start - WebView Setting
        if (webSite != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(webSite)
        }

        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true // js active
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true // componenet load
        webSettings.allowContentAccess = true
        webSettings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        webSettings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH)
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true)
        // End - WebView Setting

    }// End -OnCreate

    // Start - BackPressed CurrentView
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack()
        } else
            super.onBackPressed()
    } // End - BackPressed CurrentView
    
    // Start - SwipeRefresh
    private fun refreshApp() {
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener {
            webView?.reload()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } // End- SwipeRefresh


} // finish MainActivity
```

I hope someone can solve this case. thanks :)

Comment: Well if you managed to pass all the data around, I don't really understand what the problem is. Do you get any error? Try to print the URL when you press the button, maybe it needs to be URL encoded to escape the slashes and other symbols. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder

Comment: i don't know how to forwarding the "URL" to "WebViewActivity" with the "Button" from the "DetailActivity"...

Comment: for more details code you can check the full code from my repository on github. i hope you also check it the wireframe . thanks

Comment: @RazvanS. I've updated the question and changed my code here. can you check it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73178179/18107221)  .thanks